# How to use datagrid in HTML5

Tags: html

I've a flex application for one of my client and he is planning to upgrade it into HTML5. This application contains a few pages which contains simple UI controls like data grid, combo box etc. I'm not familiar which HTML5. Is there any control in HTML5 close to Data grid combo box.

Also, if there is any similar controls, how can I populate these controls with my existing .Net code (Data layer to load/store date into the database). Any help on this will be appreciated.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 4):

The `datagrid` element was removed from HTML5 [a long time ago](http://blog.whatwg.org/tag/datagrid#gone).  Typically you implement these sort of controls via some sort of JavaScript toolkit.  All of these have a grid widget:

- [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) (see also [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net/))
- [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/)