# How to add an object as a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the api I was able to retrieve the info i needed trough the following endpoints and create the following object.

```
 var lego = {
    "name" : item.name,
    "followers" : item.follower_count,
    "created" : item.created_at,
    "updated" : item.updated_at
    }

<datagrid id = "topicGrid" data='[{}]'>
          <datagrid-column head="Topic" content-key="name"></datagrid-column>
          <datagrid-column head="Followers" content-key="followers"></datagrid-column>
          <datagrid-column-time head="Created" content-key="created" format="date"></datagrid-column-time>
          <datagrid-column-time head="Updated" content-key="updated" format="date"></datagrid-column-time>
    </datagrid>
```

I would like to somehow append the "lego" object in the new data attribute ?
Now i tried something like
`setAttribute("data", lego);` but my knowledge here is limited.
Any help is apreciated. Thank you.

Update:
I tried passing the object as a string but I only get the last element of the object. Kind of like it's looping trough the whole object and stopping at the last one.
`$('datagrid').attr('data', JSON.stringify(lego));`

**My solution**

```
$.get( "..." ).done(function( data ) {
     var legoArr = []
     $.each(data.topics, function(index,item) {
        var lego = {
          "name" : item.name, 
          "followers" : item.follower_count,
          "created" : item.created_at,
          "updated" : item.updated_at
        };  
            legoArr.push(lego);
    });

   $('datagrid').attr('data', JSON.stringify(legoArr)); 
});
```

Comment: as you are using `Object` in this case you can `JSON.stringyfy` it and set it like `setAttribute("data", JSON.stringify(lego));`

Comment: As marked [jquery], `$("#topicGrid").attr("data", lego)` - but I would put it to you that you're not using `data-` attribute correctly (note `data-`, so data-lego= or data-data=).

Comment: thank you for your replies @freedomn-m I tried it already with both versions but no success.

Comment: *"no success"* - it didn't update the data- attribute?  It didn't store it in the data store?  Or some other "no success" based on how you're using it.  Please try to be specific.   Maybe you could include a working snippet (or [mcve]) rather than the psuedo-html (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9969092/2181514)

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry... it didn't update the data attribute.I passed json in the data attribute ```$('datagrid').attr('data', JSON.stringify(lego))``` ...which is an improvement .... but I only get the last element.

Comment: Using `.data(..` doesn't update the html.  Using `.attr` only *reads* a single entry in the collection but *sets* all of them.  A quick check confirms that in `.attr(key, value)` `value` **must be a string** (so stringify should be ok).  https://jsfiddle.net/yfbuqce0/  Can you update your question with what you've tried?